# Need help in Xpath 1.0 and 2.0 Expression using concat

Tags: xpath, conditional-statements

I'm pulling up images dynamically based on EmployerName field using the below function.

```
concat("C:\Projects\GlobalResourceSet\Images\",$EmployerName,"_banner_2013.png")
```

It works fine.

But, If the EmployerName is wrong or its empty I should display a default image.

How can we do that using both Xpath 1.0 & 2.0

Any help will be thankful...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a rather bizarre solution for XPath 1.0 like this:

```
substring(S, 1, string-length(S) * number(C))
```

where S is a string and C is a boolean condition. If C is false, number(C) is 0, so nothing is output. If C is true, number(C) is 1, so the whole string is output. So the effect is "if condition C is true then output S else output nothing"; and you can combine this with another expression using the inverse condition to output different strings based on the value of the condition.

Or you could move to XPath 2.0, where life is much more boring.

Answer (score 2):

In XPath 2.0, you could also do following:

```
concat("C:\Projects\GlobalResourceSet\Images\",
  ($EmployerName[. != ''], 'default')[1],
  "_banner_2013.png"
)
```

This puts both the employer name (if set) and the "default image name" in a sequence and then selects the first of both.

*Newlines added for readability, can be removed arbitrarily.*

Answer (score 1):

In xpath 2.0 this could work

```
if ($EmployerName = "") then "C:\Projects\GlobalResourceSet\Images\default.png" else concat("C:\Projects\GlobalResourceSet\Images\",$EmployerName,"_banner_2013.png")
```

Comment: Thanks jirka... Could you please provide solution for xpath 1.0 which is very important...

Comment: Are you working with pure xpath or with some other language which uses xpath (like xslt?¨)

Comment: I am working a CCM tool called StreamServe Persuasion. In that tool I'm using this. Yes. You're right.. Like XSLT...

Comment: In xslt you could use xsl:choose possibility to achieve what you need. I'm not sure if it is possible in pure xpath 1.0 (IMO not). Unfortunately I don't know anything abou StreamServe. I'm sorry.